# How do I load STereoLithography (.stl) file to WPF?

Tags: wpf, 3d

After loading the model I would like be able to rotate it and put points around it.

If there's a workaround like converting it to 3D MAX and then loading it would be good as well althought I'll be glad not to do that.

Comment: Well doing this manually would require a **very** good understanding of the file structure. Or are you after a third-party library?

Comment: Hi Adam Houldsworth,  third party or open source would be great as well.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy, here is the file format specs. Careful about ASCII and Binary types.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)

Regarding rotation, look for a Trackball implementation, like this one:

http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~crawfis/Graphics/VirtualTrackball.html

Answer (score 0):

For those coming to this page 11 years later, here is a sample project which uses WinForms (*which can be convertible to WPF*). It is rendered in the window using the OpenTK graphics library.

https://github.com/batu92k/STL-Viewer

The code repository provides a visualization tool for binary and ASCII-formatted STL files.